# InvalidOperationException - The type LogWriter cannot be constructed. You must configure the container to supply this value

Tags: logging, .net-4.0, enterprise-library, enterprise-library-5, biztalk-2016

When I am trying to log something from a BizTalk orchestration I am getting below error message in the eventlog.

```
Error using Info(System.String,System.String): Resolution of the dependency failed, type = "Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.LogWriter", name = "(none)".
Exception occurred while: while resolving.
Exception is: InvalidOperationException - The type LogWriter cannot be constructed. You must configure the container to supply this value.
-----------------------------------------------
At the time of the exception, the container was:

  Resolving Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.LogWriter,(none)
 Inner exception: The type LogWriter cannot be constructed. You must configure the container to supply this value.
```

For logging in BizTalk orchestration, I have created a custom .net component which is using Microsoft Enterprise Library 5. The configuration of the Entlib logging is there in a dedicated file and from the BizTalk config files `BTSNTSvc.exe.config` and `BTSNTSvc64.exe.config`, the `entlib.config` file is referenced. I am using BizTalk 2016 and VS2015.

I am trying to log a text in a flat text file.

Answer (score 0):

There is a msdn forum thread regarding this issue. https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/8edb589c-a488-49ec-aca7-5c5219940fbb/biztalk-enterprise-library-logging-issue?forum=biztalkgeneral

Not sure why you are trying to use Enterprise library to trace logs to a text file. ETW is a recommended and high performance instrumentation meant for this purpose. Please refer the article https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/30523.biztalk-server-2013-r2-instrumenting-an-orchestration-with-etw.aspx .